# Firestore - Get document's subobject instead of FIRDocumentReference

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Question**: Is there any way to receive full subobject in document instead of FIRDocumentReference fields?

**Example:**

Actual result of document.data():

```
{
    amount = 1;
    weight = 70;
    item = "<FIRDocumentReference: 0x60200266c0c0>";
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    amount = 1;
    weight = 70;
    item = {
       id = 12;
       name = "QWE"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if it's possible to automatically follow document reference type fields when getting a document, the answer is no, it's not possible.  You have to write code to use the document reference object to `get()` the other document.